# Record array of objects with a sequelize transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I need to record an array of objects in a sequelize transaction.

I got a sequelize transaction where I record a Project(for example). Then I need to record some Tasks, I did it with the bulkCreate, but then I realize that I scaped the transaction calling the bulkCreate direct from the model Task.

```
try {
  const transaction = await db.transaction(t => {
    return Project.create(
      { ...req.body.projectFull.entity },
      { transaction: t }
    ).then(
      projectCreated => {
        let tarefas = req.body.projectFull.tasks;
        const addProjectId = function(object) {
          object.projectId = projectCreated.dataValues.id;
          return object;
        };
        let criarTarefas = tarefas.map(addProjectId);
        Task.bulkCreate(criarTarefas);
      },
      { transaction: t }
    );
  });
```

I expect to have the bulkCreate working inside my transaction not directly from the model. The code I provides works fine and record the data, but It scapes the transaction on bulkCreate

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have to do this similar thing, and i didn't get to it yet, but i had read up on it back then and the example is as follows

```
return sequelize.transaction(t => {

  // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Abraham',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(user => {
    return user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, {transaction: t});
  });

}).then(result => {
  // Transaction has been committed
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
}).catch(err => {
  // Transaction has been rolled back
  // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
});
```

It looks to me like the comment above might be your problem... "make sure you return them"... you may have missed the return in the second part of your chain

Comment: I just added the "return" as you said. Please if you figure out how to use the bulkcreate inside transaction, don't forget to post here.